# Set parameterized virtual interface for array of agents

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I am trying to create virtual interface with parameterized value for an array of agents.

```
interface trig_if #(parameter width=16) (input clk, input reset);
    logic [width-1 :0] en;
    logic [width-1 :0] trig_out;
endinterface
```

```
module tb_top; 
..
..
trig_if #(.width(16)) trig1;
trig_if #(.width(8)) trig2;
trig_if #(.width(9)) trig3;
...

uvm_config_db#(virtual trig_if#(16))::set(null, "uvm_test_top.env.tagent[0].*", "trig_vif", trig1);
uvm_config_db#(virtual trig_if#(8))::set(null, "uvm_test_top.env.tagent[0].*", "trig_vif", trig2);
uvm_config_db#(virtual trig_if#(9))::set(null, "uvm_test_top.env.tagent[0].*", "trig_vif", trig3);
..
endmodule
```

```
//Env
class env extends uvm_env;
..
agent tagent[];//dynamic array
..
tagent = new[3];
..
for (int i=0; i < 3; i++) begin
  tagent[i] = agent::type_id::create($sformatf("tagent[%0d]",i), this);
end
..
endclass
```

```
//driver
class driver extends uvm_driver;
virtual trig_if vif;
..
..
if(!uvm_config_db#(virtual trig_if)::get(this, "", "trig_vif", vif))
  `uvm_fatal("NOVIF", {"Virtual interface must be set for: ", get_full_name(), ".vif"})
..
endclass
```

`
Error msg:
Virtual interface must be set for:uvm_test_top.env.tagent[1].driver

From this error, my understanding is the virtual interface created inside the driver getting 16 as width instead of the exact parameterized width which is 8.

How to pass the parameter value to agent/driver without parameterizing the agent/driver class?

Can anyone have idea on this please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Please try after modification as below:

```
module tb_top; 
..
..
trig_if #(.width(16)) trig1;
trig_if #(.width(8)) trig2;
trig_if #(.width(9)) trig3;
...

uvm_config_db#(virtual trig_if#(16))::set(null, "uvm_test_top.env.tagent[0].*", "trig_vif_16b", trig1);
uvm_config_db#(virtual trig_if#(8))::set(null, "uvm_test_top.env.tagent[0].*", "trig_vif_8b", trig2);
uvm_config_db#(virtual trig_if#(9))::set(null, "uvm_test_top.env.tagent[0].*", "trig_vif_9b", trig3);
..
endmodule
```

Driver:

```
//driver
class driver extends uvm_driver;
virtual trig_if  #(.width(16)) vif_16;
virtual trig_if  #(.width(8)) vif_8;
virtual trig_if  #(.width(9)) vif_9;
..
..
if(!uvm_config_db#(virtual trig_if#(16))::get(this, "", "trig_vif_16b", vif_16))
  `uvm_fatal("NOVIF", {"Virtual interface must be set for: ", get_full_name(), ".vif16b"})
if(!uvm_config_db#(virtual trig_if#(8))::get(this, "", "trig_vif_8b", vif_8))
  `uvm_fatal("NOVIF", {"Virtual interface must be set for: ", get_full_name(), ".vif8b"})
if(!uvm_config_db#(virtual trig_if#(9))::get(this, "", "trig_vif_9b", vif_9))
  `uvm_fatal("NOVIF", {"Virtual interface must be set for: ", get_full_name(), ".vif9b"})
..
endclass
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am trying to develop env in a generic way as VIP. The virtual interface is declared explicitly in driver for different width values.  I am trying to declare virtual interface to support different width in generic way.

Comment: There are many ways to do this. Here is one of them: http://verificationhorizons.verificationacademy.com/volume-7_issue-3/articles/stream/polymorphic-interfaces-an-alternative-for-systemverilog-interfaces_vh-v7-i3.pdf